# JAXB Web Services: Multiple Object Marshalling

Tags: xml, web-services, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I can marshal and unmarshal 1 object with no problems (in netbeans); I need to know how to do this with multiple objects? I can't generate anything but null pointer exceptions when trying to unmarshal 3 objects into an array from XML; so I don't even know if I've marshalled the 3 out correctly. I know the basic idea of declaring the object, then using the jaxbu or jaxbm command, but I'd like to see this working for more than one object.

**TLDR: How do I marshal/unmarshal multiple objects of a single class into/out of XML?? THANKS

Code I have that marshals one object from XML:

```
try {
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance ("myOffers");
Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller ();
myOffers.Offer flight = (myOffers.Offer) u.unmarshal( new FileInputStream( "offers.xml" ));

System.out.println ("Airline is  : " + flight.getAirline());
System.out.println ("Origin is : " + flight.getOrigin());
System.out.println ("Destination is : " + flight.getDestination());
System.out.println ("Seats available : " + flight.getSeats());
System.out.println("Proximity to City Centre is : " + flight.getProximity());
System.out.println("Currency : " + flight.fare.getCurrency());
System.out.println("Value : " + flight.fare.getValue());
```

} catch (JAXBException e) {    System.out.println("Error " + e);}

ok so the Xml is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:offer xmlns:ns2="http://simple.example.com/CInfoXmlDoc">
    <Origin>Nottingham</Origin>
    <Destination>Istanbul</Destination>
    <Airline>Lufthansa</Airline>
    <Proximity>10</Proximity>
    <Seats>260</Seats>
    <Fare>
        <Currency>GBP</Currency>
        <Value>300</Value>
    </Fare>
</ns2:offer>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:offer xmlns:ns2="http://simple.example.com/CInfoXmlDoc">
    <Origin>Birmingham</Origin>
    <Destination>Cairo</Destination>
    <Airline>Monarch</Airline>
    <Proximity>15</Proximity>
    <Seats>350</Seats>
    <Fare>
        <Currency>GBP</Currency>
        <Value>300</Value>
    </Fare>
</ns2:offer>
```

Which was generated by my marshal code found here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
int i = 0;
int arraySize = 2;

myOffers.Offer offer[] = new myOffers.Offer[arraySize];
offer[i] = new myOffers.Offer();
offer[i].fare = new myOffers.Offer.Fare();

offer[i].setAirline("Lufthansa");
offer[i].setOrigin("Nottingham");
offer[i].setDestination("Istanbul");
offer[i].setSeats(260);
offer[i].setProximity(10);
offer[i].fare.currency = "GBP";
offer[i].fare.value = 300;

i++;
offer[i] = new myOffers.Offer();
offer[i].fare = new myOffers.Offer.Fare();
offer[i].setAirline("Monarch");
offer[i].setOrigin("Birmingham");
offer[i].setDestination("Cairo");
offer[i].setSeats(350);
offer[i].setProximity(15);
offer[i].fare.currency = "GBP";
offer[i].fare.value = 300;


try {
int n = 0;
FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("offers.xml");
javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext jaxbCtx = javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(offer[n].getClass().getPackage().getName());
javax.xml.bind.Marshaller marshaller = jaxbCtx.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8"); //NOI18N
marshaller.setProperty(javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);


while (n < arraySize)
{ 
marshaller.marshal(offer[n], f);
n++;
}
} catch (javax.xml.bind.JAXBException ex) {
// XXXTODO Handle exception
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("global").log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex); //NOI18N
}
}
```

XSD FILE :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="http://simple.example.com/CInfoXmlDoc"
        xmlns="http://simple.example.com/CInfoXmlDoc">                
<xsd:element name="offer">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Origin" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Destination" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Airline" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Proximity" type="xsd:int"/>
            <xsd:element name="Seats" type="xsd:int"/>
            <xsd:element name="Date" type="xsd:date"/>
            <xsd:element name="Fare">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="Currency" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element name="Value" type="xsd:int"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
             </xsd:element>
             <xsd:attribute></xsd:attribute>
         </xsd:sequence>             
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Comment: Any ideas?? I'm still working on this....

Comment: @Dave Jarvis: I can show you my code that marshals one object in from XML if you like?

Comment: I've added comments. Still wondering how my XSD file should look, which is now included. The XSD has to be right for the Marshal/Unmarshal code to work surely?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create a root element called Offers that contain all the Offer elements. This way you would unmarshal the Offers element and inside it there will be a method for retrieving the list of Offer elements.

--added example--

```
<xsd:complexType name="offers">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="offersList" type="Offers" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: Thank you. It's based on an XSD schema:

Comment: Where would the root element be in the XSD schema? I can't fit the schema in my post..

Comment: finally got my XSD in the post. Lol. ahh. Would be so kind as to indicate where/how the root element should look? I'm so confused, I just need some direction now..

Comment: @Luke Evans - You need to wrap your offer element with an offers element.

Comment: how do you create a root element?